# ManagedContent how to create records?

Tags: apex, commerce-cloud, b2b

I'm working on a Salesforce Apex code where I'm trying to create a new record of a custom object (ProductMedia) and assign it the Ids of other records (Product2 and ManagedContent). However, I'm encountering an error "Variable does not exist: Id" at line 17, column 46. Below is the relevant section of the code:

```
    Product2 product = new Product2();
product.Name = 'Product Test';
product.ProductCode = 'PT123';
insert product;

Id productId = product.Id;

ConnectApi.ManagedContentBodyInput contentBody = new ConnectApi.ManagedContentBodyInput();

ConnectApi.ManagedContentDocumentInput managedContentInput = new ConnectApi.ManagedContentDocumentInput();
managedContentInput.title = 'Teste';
managedContentInput.contentBody = contentBody;

ConnectApi.ManagedContentDocument managedContentDocument = ConnectApi.ManagedContent.createManagedContent(managedContentInput);

String cmsContentId = managedContentDocument.Id;

Id electronicMediaGroupId = '2mgAZ00000001jXYAQ';

ProductMedia productMedia = new ProductMedia();
productMedia.ProductId = productId;
productMedia.ElectronicMediaId = cmsContentId;
productMedia.ElectronicMediaGroupId = electronicMediaGroupId; 
insert productMedia;
```